# ionic2 // Can't use my module in a page component

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng-modules

I'm upgrading my application from the beta.11 to the RC3. But I have a problem with a component I used in the beta.11 version.

Basically, I created a modular component "MyMessage", which is a angular2 component (and not a NgModule). I use this module in a page component "MessagesPage".

Here is what was working with the beta.11 :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-message',
  templateUrl: 'my-message.component.html',
})
export class MyMessage {
  // ... 
}

import { MyMessage } from '../components/my-message.component';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'messages.html' // Template contains <my-message> tags
  //, directives: [ MyMessage ]
})
export class MessagesPage {
  messages: Array<MyMessage>;
  // ...
}
```

But I have a dependency problem :

> Cannot find name 'MyMessage'

So I tried to move my 'MyMessage' component to a NgModule, which seemed to be the solution.

```
import { MyMessage } from './components/my-message.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ IonicModule.forRoot(MyMessage) ],
  declarations: [ MyMessage ]
})
export class MyMessageModule { }
```

And in the `app.module.ts`, I added `MyMessageModule` in the `imports` section.
But I still have the previous error, I don't understand what I missed.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `MyMessageModule` as below :

```
import { MyMessage } from './chat-message.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyMessage ],
  exports : [ MyMessage ]
})
export class MyMessageModule { }
```

Comment: thank you ! I tried that but I still have the problem. I also tried to remove all my calls to this module, but keep only one in a template, but I got this error in the javascript console : Unexpected directive 'MyMessage' imported by the module 'MyMessageModule'

Comment: You have to remove `MyMessage` from `imports` decorator metadata of `MyMessageModule`

Comment: Ok it works. I'm lost with all these decorator metadata. Last question : I load and fill in my component from the typescript classes, but it seems that my class is not exported everywhere because this line fails : `messages: Array<MyMessage>;` (`Cannot find name 'MyMessage'`)

Comment: set `messages` like `messages: MyMessage[];`

Comment: doesn't work either :( 
it works when I import it manually (i don't think it's the best way but at least it works)

Comment: actually I don't have the errors anymore, but my <my-message> tags in templates are not replace. I still have them in the DOM.